# Is it possible to store Meta Data in a Notebook?

Tags: stylesheet, metadata, headers-footers

I am creating multiple notebooks for a textbook that I would like to print with headers on every page.  For example,

Notebook 1: Chapter 1, Section 1, "Addition"

Notebook 2: Chapter 1, Section 2, "Subtraction"

Notebook 3: Chapter 2, Section 1, "Multiplication"

Notebook 4: Chapter 2, Section 2, "Division"

Notebook 5: Chapter 2, Section 3, "Extra Stuff"
.
.
.

The headers for each notebook will contain the chapter number, section number and Heading Name as shown above. I understand how to work with headers and private stylesheets and counters.  I do not need help with that.

I would like to know how to programmatically set and access meta data for each notebook.  I want the meta data to contains numbers (chapter number and section number) and a string (Heading Name).  Can I store hidden meta data in a notebook somehow?  If so, how is this done and how can I access it once I've done it?

If I can do this, then I can use a private stylesheet to pull this hidden meta data in from the notebook to place in the headers.  Any ideas of how to store meta data like this in a notebook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `TaggingRules`.  Once you have set the metadata it is embedded in the notebook.  It can be retrieved at any time using `CurrentValue`.  If the meta data changes it can be reset.  Only one meta data object can be set per notebook so separate items should be put in a list.

```
metadata = {1, 2, 3};

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], TaggingRules -> {"meta" -> metadata}]

metadata = CurrentValue[{TaggingRules, "meta"}]
```

Comment: sorry, your answer needs some more explanation for me to understand it. He said chapter number and title. How would you call them in your structure inside, for example, a text cell?

Comment: @NicholasG I've only answered the question regarding how to store meta data in a notebook.  You can put anything in the variable, `metadata`.  The list `{1, 2, 3}` is just for example.